# Push Google Analytics Tracking Event on Section / Image View

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have section on our products pages towards the bottom that shows similar products. Is it possible to use event tracking to track when someone sees them? I am currently doing click tracking on them, but it would be nice to be able to track a percent of click through for different suggestion types and to know what percent of people scroll down enough to see them on smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use something like this jQuery 'in view' plugin to fire an event when that element comes into view: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

Then, when that happens, you could fire a GA event. Depending on your use-case (whether or not you want to fire more than one event if the user scrolls away again and then brings it back into view), you may want to only bind once.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't currently load jQuery, so I don't know if I want to add it just for this. I was hoping for a "lighter" solution.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/robflaherty/jquery-scrolldepth

seems to be well maintained and documented. It will do more than the one Remy Sharp suggested on his blog post, which is kind of old-ish by now. It can track scrolling-depth and detect when elements come into view. Once you have both you can do what you want with events, so you can calculate CTR on visible elements/sections.

There is also a non-jQuery fork, which is not as updated but might serve just as well:

https://github.com/leighmcculloch/gascrolldepth.js